# server admin issue: dns forward zone issue

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

This is my forward zone file:

```
[root@m6 named]# cat ourlinuxtutorials.com.db
$TTL 1D 86400
@ IN SOA m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com. root.m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com. (
0 ; serial
1D ; refresh
1H ; retry
1W ; expire
3H ) ; minimum
IN NS m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com.
IN A 127.0.0.1
m6 IN A 192.34.61.117
```

Is the error due to:

```
<<< @ IN SOA m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com. root.m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com. (
```

Here `m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com` is the hostname.

So line:

```
IN NS m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com.
```

should mean `m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com` is the name server but it was not. That must have been error?

Also there are errors when the named was restarted:

```
[root@m6 named]# service named restart
Stopping named: [ OK ]
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
dns_master_load: ourlinuxtutorials.com.db:1: extra input text
zone ourilinuxtutorials.com/IN: loading from master file ourlinuxtutorials.com.db failed: extra input text
zone ourilinuxtutorials.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/ourilinuxtutorials.com/IN: extra input text
zone 61.34.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
[FAILED]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think these lines:

```
<<< @ IN SOA m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com. root.m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com. (
```

Should be like this:

```
IN SOA  m6.ourlinuxtutorials.com. root.ourlinuxtutorials.com. (
```

Take a look at this [sample domain master file](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/mydomain.html).

#### Example

```
$TTL    86400 ; 24 hours could have been written as 24h or 1d
$ORIGIN example.com.
@  1D  IN    SOA ns1.example.com.   hostmaster.example.com. (
                  2002022401 ; serial
                  3H ; refresh
                  15 ; retry
                  1w ; expire
                  3h ; minimum
                 )
       IN  NS     ns1.example.com. ; in the domain
       IN  NS     ns2.smokeyjoe.com. ; external to domain
       IN  MX  10 mail.another.com. ; external mail provider
; server host definitions
ns1    IN  A      192.168.0.1  ;name server definition     
www    IN  A      192.168.0.2  ;web server definition
ftp    IN  CNAME  www.example.com.  ;ftp server definition
; non server domain hosts
bill   IN  A      192.168.0.3
fred   IN  A      192.168.0.4
```

Also it looks like a typo on the first line:

I think it should just be `$TTL 1D`, not `$TTL 1D 86400`. That's what the error is complaining about, line #1:

```
dns_master_load: ourlinuxtutorials.com.db:1: extra input text
```

Comment: did as above..still no luck

Comment: See my updates.